# How to raise log level on one logger

Tags: logging, configuration, nlog

I have the following nlog configuration. I would just like to not log any non-Error messages from `Meazure.Core.SiteContext`.

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.GrowlNotify" />
        <add assembly="Gelf4NLog.Target" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log.log" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${exception:format=Type,Message,StackTrace:innerFormat=Type,Message,StackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10:innerExceptionSeparator=\n\t}" maxArchiveFiles="1" archiveAboveSize="1000000" />
        <target name="dev" xsi:type="Console" />
        <target name="growl" type="GrowlNotify" host="" password="" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="Meazure.Core.SiteContext" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dev" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="growl" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

It's not working! I still get messages like this in `file`

```
2016-03-23 15:08:58.0125|DEBUG|Meazure.Core.SiteContext|Closed connection at 2016-03-23 3:08:58 PM -07:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final rule works for the combination:

- loggername
- minlevel

So events with loggername "Meazure.Core.SiteContext" and minlevel "error" won't go to logger rules 2-4. But if the level is "debug", it will.

The best way to accomplish this is to use the [Null target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Null-target):

new target:

```xml
  <target name="null" xsi:type="Null" />
```

rules:

```xml
 <logger name="Meazure.Core.SiteContext" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" final="true" />
 <logger name="Meazure.Core.SiteContext" writeTo="null" final="true"/>
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dev" />
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
 <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="growl" />
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense